# how to I print a grid in java?

Tags: java

Im trying to print a 3 x 3 grid of zeros. right now im getting 9 rows of zeros in the first column

```
public void displayBoard() {    
    
    
        for (int row = 0; row<3; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column<3; column++) {
                        System.out.println("-------");
                        System.out.print("|"+ board.getCell(row, column));
            
                        System.out.println("|");
                }   
            
            
            }       
        
        System.out.println("-------");
    }
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoacM.png)

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: In your image, is that the output you have now, or is that the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

Output display like this can be a bit of a dark art.  You have to be able to break it down into small bits and handle each part in turn.

So a table like this:

```
-------------
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
-------------
```

Has 1 top line of dashes, three numbers surrounded by `|`, and then a final line at the bottom.  Not tested:

```
System.out.println( "-------------" );
System.out.print( "|" );
System.out.print( " 1 " );
System.out.print( "|" );
System.out.print( " 0 " );
System.out.print( "|" );
System.out.print( " 1 " );
System.out.println( "|" );
System.out.println( "-------------" );
```

Notice I used `print` instead of `println` because otherwise I'd get a blank line instead of a solid line across.  But trying to break down the problem into smaller bits like this can help you understand how to do each part.

So looking at the above, I did this (which does compile and run correctly):

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      int[] binary = {1,0,1};
      System.out.println( "-------------" );
      for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
         System.out.print( "| "+ binary[i] + " " );
      }
      System.out.println( "|" );
      System.out.println( "-------------" );
   }
```

This is obviously an assignment, so I'll let you finish the rest, but you should be able to see the pattern here.  Try working it out with some simple print statements first, then try putting those statements into a loop.

Comment: I feel like that part is correct I think my issue is with the loops

Comment: Try working out what you need to print first, then work out how to put those into a loop.  Just asking for a solution isn't the right way to learn, you really do need to work out how those loops really work.

Comment: Im not just asking for a solution, When I go through the loops it seems to work to me and just wanted some other eyes to look at it.

Comment: Honest answer: your solution looks wrong to me.  That isn't a table that you printed.  Ask your instructor before you turn it in, imo.